# Inserting Styled HTML Table inside InfoWindow.content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps-api-3

Greeting Overflowers,

I'm building some tool using Google Maps API
and I would like to insert some styled HTML table instead of the plain text
I was not successful, though. So, any ideas ? Thanks !

```
<style type="text/css">
    html { height: 100% }
    body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
    table.colorful {
        font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #333333;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #999999;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table.colorful th {
        background: #b5cfd2 url('blueCell.jpg');
        border-width: 1px;
        padding: 8px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #999999;
    }
    table.colorful td {
        background: #dcddc0 url('greenCell.jpg');
        border-width: 1px;
        padding: 8px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #999999;
    }
    #mapCanvas { height: 100% }
</style>
```

and here:

```
var info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                position: dcs[i].coord,
                content: ""
            });

            info.content = "<table class=\"table.colorful\"><tr><th>Server</th><th>Site</th><th>IP</th><th>Services</th></tr>"

            for(var j in dcs[i].servers) {
                info.content += "<tr><td><b>" + dcs[i].servers[j].name + "</b></td><td>" + dcs[i].servers[j].site + "</td><td>" + dcs[i].servers[j].ip + "</td><td>" + dcs[i].servers[j].services + "</td></tr>";
            }

            info.content += "</table>";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are SO close, you'll need to use info.setContent() instead.

```
info.setContent(element);
```

Comment: In my case it is a dom Object but AFAIK you could use a HTML string

http://code.google.com/intl/da-DK/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#InfoWindow

Comment: @Kenned: the table is added but it is plain and without the specific style :(

Comment: According to the documentation it should apply, are you sure that there is nothing interfering?
Where I use it My style does apply.

Comment: Kenned: My mistake. I used table.colorful as the table class instead of colorful. Thank you very much !

Comment: You're very welcome, I know how it is to stare myself blind at a problem